# Surround with {% trans "" %} tag

Tags: django, pydev, emmet

What would be the simplest why to bind a pydev keyboard shortcut to a command which surrounds the selected <kbd>text</kbd> with a django `trans` template tag, modifying it to `{% trans "`<kbd>text</kbd>`" %}`?

Answer (score 1):

Note: the answer below is if you're in the PyDev editor (.py files)... This support is not currently available for the Django Template editor (so, please let me know which editor you're actually using where you want that feature).

You currently can't set templates to a given keyboard shortcut.

Now, having said that, you can make it work by creating a custom scripting command.

It should be pretty straightforward, just follow the split lines (`Ctrl+2, sl`) as an example.

I.e.: in your PyDev install you should have a Python module at plugins/org.python.pydev.jython/jysrc/pyedit_create_lines_on_commas.py, create a copy of it -- but make sure it still starts with 'pyedit_', then change the function SplitTextInCommas to do what you want and change the ACTIVATION_STRING to something else -- i.e.: if you change it to `x`, you have to do `Ctrl+2, x` to activate it.

Also, you should probably also set the location of 'additional jython scripts' to a folder where you put that module (window > preferences > pydev > scripting pydev).

It may also be worth taking a look at: http://pydev.org/manual_articles_scripting.html for some more info on scripting PyDev.